# How do I set default value for Flask-WTF in Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have tried finding a way to write the code below using flask WTF and Jinja but the value field is not been passed to my backend

**Code 1**

```
<form action="{{url_for('cart')}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="{{item.productid}}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
</form>
```

What I want to achieve is for a variable called productid to be passed to backend so I can use it to run queries. When I do it as above, it passes the variable to backend but I will experience an error later.

The code I tried using was as follows

**Code 2**

```
<form action="{{url_for('cart')}}" method="POST">
    {{ form2.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form2.productid(value=item.productid) }}
    {{ form2.btn_identifier }}
    {{ form2.submit2(class="btn btn-danger") }}
</form>
```

But the above does not capture value field and thus I have nothing to work with.

How do I set the value to be a variable called item.productid? What is the equivalent of Code 1 above in Jinja?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd set the field values in the `GET` request method.

Given a form definition of:

```
class TestForm(Form):
    product_id = HiddenField()

# use a data dictionary
my_data = {'product_id': 1000}
_form1 = TestForm(data=my_data)
```

Use a Python object

```
@dataclass
class FormObject:
    product_id: int

# use a Python object
my_obj = FormObject(product_id=2000)
_form2 = TestForm(obj=my_obj)
```

Set a field's value directly:

```
# Set a field's data directly
_form3 = TestForm()
_form3.product_id.data = 3000
```

Single file example, note `form4`, where the value is set in the Jinja template:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from wtforms import Form, HiddenField

app = Flask(__name__)


class TestForm(Form):
    product_id = HiddenField()


html_template = '''
    <h1>Set via data dictionary:{{ form1.product_id.data }}</h1>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="" name="Form1">
        {{ form1.product_id }}
    </form>
    <hr>
        
    <h1>Set via Python object:{{ form2.product_id.data }}</h1>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="" name="Form2">
        {{ form2.product_id }}
    </form>
    <hr>
    
    <h1>Set form field data:{{ form3.product_id.data }}</h1>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="" name="Form3">
        {{ form3.product_id }}
    </form>
    <hr>
        
    <form role="form" method="post" action="" name="Form4">
        {{ form4.product_id(value=4000) }}
    </form>

       
'''


@dataclass
class FormObject:
    product_id: int


@app.route('/')
def custom_form():

    # use a data dictionary
    my_data = {'product_id': 1000}
    _form1 = TestForm(data=my_data)

    # use a Python object
    my_obj = FormObject(product_id=2000)
    _form2 = TestForm(obj=my_obj)

    # Set the field's data directly
    _form3 = TestForm()
    _form3.product_id.data = 3000

    # will set value in Jinja2
    _form4 = TestForm()

    return render_template_string(html_template, form1=_form1, form2=_form2, form3=_form3, form4=_form4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```